# Returning JSON to client incorrectly MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am hitting the controller but when I get back to the javascript the JSON being returned is not formatted correctly to populate the select list. Its returning this as the Name ""System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Course_C81CDD1DDC4D486F471F64D1F95990CD35185‌​07F0B5BB9F718C0910A56B73D12"" and the Value=null for each course. The data coming out of the controller is fine and queried correctly so ther eis something wrong with my javascript code

Here are my controllers:

```
public JsonResult GetCourses(int facilityId)
{
    return Json(GetCoursesSelectList(facilityId), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private SelectList GetCoursesSelectList(int id)
{
    var Courses = db.Courses.Distinct().Where(a => a.FacilityId == id).ToList();
    SelectList list = new SelectList(Courses);
    return list;
}
```

Here is my JavaScript function:

```
$("#ddlFacility").change(function () {
            var selectedFacility = $(this).val();

            if (selectedFacility != null && selectedFacility != '') {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCourses")", { facilityId: selectedFacility }, function (courses) {

                    var coursesSelect = $('#ddlCourse');
                    coursesSelect.empty();
                    $.each(courses, function (index, course) {
                        alert(course.Course_Name);
                        coursesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: course.CourseId,
                            text: course.Course_Name
                        }));
                    });
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: what does this do exactly `SelectList list = new SelectList(Courses);`? What is a `SelectList`?

Comment: This is a list of Courses from the database filtered by the FacilityId.  "1" Facility to "Many" Courses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert your Courses into a SelectList - it's converting it into a SelectList, which is then being converted into your JSON object, which JQuery isn't parsing the way you want.  A simple `IEnumerable<Course>` will convert properly.  Changing your controller action to the following should fix your problem:

```
  private IEnumerable<Course> GetCoursesSelectList( int id )
  {
    return db.Courses.Distinct().Where(a => a.FacilityId == id).ToList();
  }
```

**EDIT:** Created working test app, with the dropdown being populated from the controller

The View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<select id="ddlCourse"></select>

<script>
    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCourses")", { facilityId: 1 }, function (courses) {            
        var coursesSelect = $('#ddlCourse');
        coursesSelect.empty();
        $.each(courses, function (index, course) {               
            coursesSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                value: course.CourseId,
                text: course.Course_Name
            }));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
  public class HomeController : Controller
   {
      public static IEnumerable<string> items = new List<string>() { "abc", "1234" };

      public ActionResult Index()
      {
         return View( "Index" );
      }

      public JsonResult GetCourses( int facilityId )
      {
         return Json( GetCoursesSelectList( facilityId ), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
      }

      private IEnumerable<Course> GetCoursesSelectList( int id )
      {
        return db.Courses.Distinct().Where(a => a.FacilityId == id).ToList();
      }
   }
```

Comment: This will update your dropdown, did you update the code and try it?  I've updated my answer with my simple test.

Comment: This option will only add the courses that I hardcode in. I am trying to populate the Course dropdown based on the facilityId from my database.

Comment: For the test, I didn't want to go through the trouble of creating a database and populating, it was simply a proof of concept.  Changing your GetCoursesSelectList function, to the very first function I wrote (db.Courses.Distinct().Where(a => a.FacilityId == id).ToList();), which returns values from your context, will work.

Comment: I am still not getting the list to populate. The JSON has the proper items but the view is not populating correctly.

Comment: The course object in the javascript function is now undefined

Comment: I've updated my example to what yours should be exactly.. does that match what you have?

Comment: Aside from the IEnumerable<string> items portion, which is the dbcontext object in my project, they are the same.

Comment: When debugging the Javascript, the function skips to the end of the function after this line of code $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCourses")", { facilityId: selectedFacility }, function (courses) {